# SparkR - Convert dataframe into Vector/list

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, sparkr, collect

Can anyone tell me, whether we can convert data frame to list in SparkR. I am aware that collect() function helps you do that. However, it is not advisable when we use large amount of data. In python/Scala, there is a function called **local Iterator**() which will convert the data frame to list. Am struggling with that in SparkR. Can anybody help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly `collect()` is the best method to do this. You can also try: `saveAsTextFile` but in that case you probably will not obtain whole data.

Comment: If you use Cassandra 3.0 there is a possibility to use 'Materialized view' and rearrange your data on server, but it won't help you with downloading data. (you can use it to decrease ammount of data and then save it locally - if you don't need whole dataset)